# tkinter iconbipmap can't find file

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, icons

```
root=tk.Tk()
root.iconbitmap('icon.ico')
```

I have this code in my program to change the title bar icon of the tkinter window. I get this error when the code runs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\User\Desktop\translator-main\translator.py", line 14, in <module>
    root.iconbitmap('icon.ico')
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2080, in wm_iconbitmap
    return self.tk.call('wm', 'iconbitmap', self._w, bitmap)
_tkinter.TclError: bitmap "icon.ico" not defined
```

icon.ico is in the same directory as the python file.
[image]

Comment: It may be that current working directory is not the same as where the python script is.  Try printing out result of `os.getcwd()` to check.

Answer (score 0):

So first, you need to check whether python recognises this file by using the `ls` command in your IDE shell.

The first thing to do is try putting in the value as:

```
root.iconbitmap('icon.ico.ico')
```

If this doesn't work, try putting in the entire directory (remember to replace all backslashes with front-slash as it might create an error in python).

Thank You!